# Let $\{f_n\}\subset L^2([0,1])$ be such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise and $\sup \|f_n\|_{L^2}^2 < \infty$, show that $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ for $p\in [1,2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I wish to prove the following statement: Suppose $\{ f_n\} \in L^2([0,1])$, $f_n \to f$ pointwise, and $\sup \|f_n\|_{L^2}^2 < \infty$. Then $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ for $p\in [1,2)$.

Here is what I have so far: By Fatou's lemma, one can see that
$$ \int_{[0,1]} |f|^2 \ dx \leq \liminf \int_{[0,1]} |f_n|^2 \ dx < \infty $$
so indeed $f \in L^2$ as well. However, after this step, I am stuck. I tried applying Holder's inequality to yield
$$\int_{[0,1]} |f_n-f|^p \ dx \leq \left(\int_{[0,1]} |f_n-f|^2  \ dx\right)^{p/2}  $$
But this dosent seem helpful as we do not have $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$. I would appreciate any help on this problem.

Edit: After thinking for a while, I came up with the following idea using Dominated Convergence Thm. We have the bound $$\|f_n - f\|_{L^p} \leq \|f_n\|_{L^p} + \|f\|_{L^p}$$ The RHS is integrable using the Holder inequality as above. The result would then follow directly by passing the limit inside the integral. Would this approach work?

Comment: This is a very popular question and it has been answered many times. You have to use uniform integrability of $(|f_n|^{p})$.

Comment: In this case, I dont think the uniform integrability is assumed?

Comment: Boundeness of second moments implies its uniform integrability for $p<2$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Is there anything wrong with my approach using DCT?

Comment: Egoroff's theorem might come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feng as already explained why the dominated convergence argument does not work.

Here is an alternative proof, using Egoroff's theorem. It was shown in the opening post that $f$ belongs to $\mathbb L^2$, hence considering $g_n=f_n-f$, we know that $g_n\to 0$ pointwise and that $M:=\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\lVert g_n\rVert_2 <\infty$. We have to show that for each $p\in [1,2)$, $\lVert g_n\rVert_p\to 0$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Egoroff's theorem that we can find a set $A_\varepsilon\subset [0,1]$ such that $\sup_{x\in A_\varepsilon}\lvert g_n(x)\rvert\to 0$ and $\lambda\left([0,1]\setminus A_\varepsilon\right)<\varepsilon$. Consequently,
$$
\lVert g_n\rVert_p^p=\int_{A_\varepsilon} \lvert g_n(x)\rvert^p d\lambda(x)+\int_{[0,1]\setminus A_\varepsilon} \lvert g_n(x)\rvert^p d\lambda(x)\leqslant 
\sup_{x\in A_\varepsilon}\lvert g_n(x)\rvert+\int_{[0,1]\setminus A_\varepsilon} \lvert g_n(x)\rvert^p d\lambda(x).$$
For the last integral, use Hölder's inequality with the exponents $p'=2/p$ and $q'=2/(2-p)$ to get that
$$
\lVert g_n\rVert_p^p\leqslant \sup_{x\in A_\varepsilon}\lvert g_n(x)\rvert+M^p\varepsilon^{(2-p)/2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your approach using DCT is wrong. To show that $\|f_n-f\|_{L^p}\to0$ directly using DCT, you should find a $g\in L^p$ such that $|f_n-f|\leq g$ a.e. In your post, you only get $\sup_{n}\|f_n-f\|_{L^p}<+\infty$, which is NOT sufficient to conclude $\|f_n-f\|_{L^p}\to0$.

Below is my proof.

> **A well-known identity.** Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be a measurable function. For each $\lambda>0$, define
> $$E_\lambda:=\{x\in[0,1]: |f(x)|>\lambda\},$$
> then
> $$\|f\|_{L^p([0,1])}=p\int_0^\infty \lambda^{p-1}m(E_\lambda)\,d\lambda,\qquad \forall p>0.$$
> Indeed, Fubini's theorem implies that
> \begin{align*}
> \|f\|_{L^p([0,1])}&=\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)|^p\,dx=p\int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_{[0,|f(x)|]}\lambda^{p-1}\,d\lambda\right)\,dx\\
> &=p\int_{[0,1]}\int_0^\infty \chi_{[0,|f(x)|]}(\lambda)\lambda^{p-1}\,d\lambda dx\\
> &=p\int_0^\infty \lambda^{p-1}\left(\int_{[0,1]}\chi_{[0,|f(x)|]}(\lambda)\,dx\right)\,d\lambda\\
> &=p\int_0^\infty \lambda^{p-1}\left(\int_{[0,1]}\chi_{E_\lambda}(x)\,dx\right)\,d\lambda\\
> &=p\int_0^\infty \lambda^{p-1}m(E_\lambda)\,d\lambda.
> \end{align*}

Now let $\{ f_n\} \subset L^2([0,1])$ be such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise and $\sup \|f_n\|_{L^2}^2 < \infty$. By Fatou, $f\in L^2$. Hence we can assume without loss of generality that $f\equiv0$, otherwise we consider $g_n=f_n-f$. For any $\lambda>0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, we define
$$E_{n,\lambda}:=\{x\in[0,1]: |f_n(x)|>\lambda\}.$$
Since $f_n\to0$ pointwise, we have
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty E_{n,\lambda}=\emptyset, $$
then $\lim_{k\to\infty}m\left(\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty E_{n,\lambda}\right)=0$, and hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}m(E_{n,\lambda})=0,\qquad \forall \lambda>0.\tag{$*$}$$
It follows from $\sup \|f_n\|_{L^2}^2 < \infty$ that
$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\int_0^\infty \lambda m(E_{n,\lambda})\,d\lambda\leq M$$
for some $M\in(0,+\infty)$.

Now we're ready to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_{L^p}=0$ for $p\in[1,2)$. For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $R>0$ such that $R^{p-2}<\varepsilon$, then
\begin{align*}
\|f_n\|_{L^p}^p&=p\int_0^\infty \lambda^{p-1}m(E_{n,\lambda})\,d\lambda\\
&=p\int_0^R\lambda^{p-1}m(E_{n,\lambda})\,d\lambda+p\int_R^\infty\lambda^{p-1}m(E_{n,\lambda})\,d\lambda\\
&\leq p\int_0^R\lambda^{p-1}m(E_{n,\lambda})\,d\lambda+pR^{p-2}\int_R^\infty\lambda m(E_{n,\lambda})\,d\lambda\\
&\leq p\int_0^R\lambda^{p-1}m(E_{n,\lambda})\,d\lambda+pM\varepsilon;
\end{align*}
By $(*)$, $m(E_{n,\lambda})\leq 1$ and the dominated convergence theorem we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^R\lambda^{p-1}m(E_{n,\lambda})\,d\lambda=0,$$
hence
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_{L^p}^p\leq pM\varepsilon,\qquad \forall \varepsilon>0,$$
which implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_{L^p}=0$ for $p\in[1,2)$.